# Creating a function that allows me to readRDS files?

Tags: r

I just wanted to create a function which enables me to read a RDS file.. so I have the code below, and I would like for a1 to display the RDS file in Rstudio when I input test(example.RDS)

```
readRDS(paste0("C:/Users/Jack/Documents/","example.RDS")
```

works but when I try to turn it into a function, it does not work...

```
 test <- function (entry) {
        a1 <- readRDS(paste0("C:/Users/Jack/Documents/",entry))
        }
```

Comment: Could you provide the Error it returns please?

Comment: And you should remove `a1 <-`: a1 will keep in memory the name of the element in "entry" and not the actual components. If you want to give a specific name to your object saved in "entry", use the function `assign()`

Comment: You probably search for the function `get()`. This function enables you access the element stored in a1. You can also assign the value of `a1` into a new variable by `a2 <- get(a1)`.

Comment: @tacoman No, they don't. Please don't mention that function to beginners. If they can use it, they should change their approach in 99.9 % of the cases because their approach is bad practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```r
saveRDS(diamonds, '~/diamonds.rds')
#> Error in saveRDS(diamonds, "~/diamonds.rds"): object 'diamonds' not found

test <- function(entry) {
  readRDS(paste0("~/", entry))
}

test('diamonds.rds')
#> # A tibble: 53,940 x 10
#>    carat cut       color clarity depth table price     x     y     z
#>    <dbl> <ord>     <ord> <ord>   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1  0.23 Ideal     E     SI2      61.5    55   326  3.95  3.98  2.43
#>  2  0.21 Premium   E     SI1      59.8    61   326  3.89  3.84  2.31
#>  3  0.23 Good      E     VS1      56.9    65   327  4.05  4.07  2.31
#>  4  0.29 Premium   I     VS2      62.4    58   334  4.2   4.23  2.63
#>  5  0.31 Good      J     SI2      63.3    58   335  4.34  4.35  2.75
#>  6  0.24 Very Good J     VVS2     62.8    57   336  3.94  3.96  2.48
#>  7  0.24 Very Good I     VVS1     62.3    57   336  3.95  3.98  2.47
#>  8  0.26 Very Good H     SI1      61.9    55   337  4.07  4.11  2.53
#>  9  0.22 Fair      E     VS2      65.1    61   337  3.87  3.78  2.49
#> 10  0.23 Very Good H     VS1      59.4    61   338  4     4.05  2.39
#> # … with 53,930 more rows

#no need to pass string as an argument
test2 <- function(entry) {
  .string <- substitute(entry) |> as.character()
  readRDS(stringr::str_glue("~/{.string}"))
}

test2(diamonds.rds) 
#> # A tibble: 53,940 x 10
#>    carat cut       color clarity depth table price     x     y     z
#>    <dbl> <ord>     <ord> <ord>   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1  0.23 Ideal     E     SI2      61.5    55   326  3.95  3.98  2.43
#>  2  0.21 Premium   E     SI1      59.8    61   326  3.89  3.84  2.31
#>  3  0.23 Good      E     VS1      56.9    65   327  4.05  4.07  2.31
#>  4  0.29 Premium   I     VS2      62.4    58   334  4.2   4.23  2.63
#>  5  0.31 Good      J     SI2      63.3    58   335  4.34  4.35  2.75
#>  6  0.24 Very Good J     VVS2     62.8    57   336  3.94  3.96  2.48
#>  7  0.24 Very Good I     VVS1     62.3    57   336  3.95  3.98  2.47
#>  8  0.26 Very Good H     SI1      61.9    55   337  4.07  4.11  2.53
#>  9  0.22 Fair      E     VS2      65.1    61   337  3.87  3.78  2.49
#> 10  0.23 Very Good H     VS1      59.4    61   338  4     4.05  2.39
#> # … with 53,930 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>